# Application.Match Run Time Error 13 in VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

This code was working about a month ago with out any issues.

The run time error (#13) points to:

**lastRow = Application.Match(campus, subject.Range("A1:A35000"), 1) + 2**

I have run the macro a few times with it being partially successful some times. Other times it does not get any data at all.

If the macro is partially successful, what would cause the type mismatch if the data in the columns is the same through out.  All the data exported from SQL Tools and then copied and pasted to the worksheets.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim campus As String
Dim gradeCount As Integer
Dim current As String
Dim previous As String

campus = schools.Range("A" & i).Value
With subject.Range("A:A")
    Set Rng = .Find(what:=campus, _
                     After:=.Cells(.Cells.count), _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                     searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                     searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:=False)

    gradeCount = 0
    firstRow = 0
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        firstRow = Application.Match(campus, subject.Range("A1:A35000"), 0) + 2
        lastRow = Application.Match(campus, subject.Range("A1:A35000"), 1) + 2
        gs.Range("A" & rowCount).Value = schools.Range("A" & i).Value
        gs.Range("C" & rowCount).Value = schools.Range("C" & i).Value
        currentCampus = gs.Range("A" & rowCount).Value
        current = ""
        previous = ""
        For count = firstRow To lastRow
            If campus = subject.Range("A" & count).Value Then
                current = subject.Range("C" & count)
                gs.Range("A" & rowCount).Value = schools.Range("A" & i).Value
                If current <> previous Then
                    gs.Range("C" & rowCount).Value = schools.Range("C" & i).Value
                    gs.Range("D" & rowCount).Value = grade
                    gs.Range("E" & rowCount).Value = current
                    previous = current
                    gradeCount = gradeCount + 1
                    rowCount = rowCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next count
        If gradeCount > 1 Then
            gs.Range("D" & rowCount).Value = grade
            gs.Range("E" & rowCount).Value = "*"
            gs.Range("C" & rowCount).Value = schools.Range("C" & i).Value
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Can you check your `Range.Find` method for correctness? It seems that it starts searching after the very last cell of the first column?

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication that the **Match** failed to find a value.

If the same formula occupied a worksheet cell, you would see:

```
#N/A
```